# Symfony Forms - dynamic number of items

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to build a product page that will contain a form with a dynamic number of "options" (either select boxes or input fields) depending on the product.  After reading the documentation, I can't see how to create a form entity that would work when building this form.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is basically create form field of `collection` type, which will be your collection of select boxes, input fields, whatever.

Check [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and read about embeding forms, it is described pretty well ther

Your parent form:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('yourCollection', 'collection',  array(
                'type' => new ChildType(),
                'label' => 'Label for your child form',
                ));
    }
}
```

Your child form:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->add('category', 'choice')
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the idea is that I create a class for the select boxes, a separate class for input fields, and embed each of those as ArrayCollections in my main form?

Comment: exactly, class for select box need to extend `AbstractType` like your parent form